# installation problems in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

what does this mean what to do when installation is finished

```
(1) You MUST put /home/shabeer/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14, /home/shabeer/ns-allinone-2.35/lib, 
    into your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
    If it complains about X libraries, add path to your X libraries 
    into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
    If you are using csh, you can set it like:
        setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH <paths>
    If you are using sh, you can set it like:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.bashrc, you should add a line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/shabeer/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/shabeer/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
```

and either log out and in again or run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The program needs to know these paths.

Hopefully you don't need the second part, but write again if you do